Телеграм бот на питоне, ограничение количества цифр в запросе от пользователя
Как сделать, чтобы бот принимал только опредённое кол-во цифр в сообщении? Например, пользователь должен ввести айди, но айди должен быть в формате 6ХХХХХХХХ, т.е. первая цифра 6, всего цифр 9
Любое другое значение должно не приниматься
Я только начал изучать создание ботов на питоне
У меня есть такой код, который принимает только цифры без текста
def char1(message):
    global idchar
    try:
        idchar = int(message.text.strip().lower())

    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пожалуйста, введите Ваш ID')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, char1)
        return


Можно так проверить:
import re
while True:
    x = input('Введите цифры ввиде 6XXXXXXXX ->')
    if re.match('6\d{8}', x):
        print('Ok')
        break


Попробовал внедрить код в бота. В итоге из сообщения пользователя убирается первая цифра, а в ссылку подставляется 9 последующих цифр, остальные игнорируются
(след функция идет с подставкой соо пользователя в ссылку и отправки ссылки пользователю)

Возможно как-то обрабатывать отдельно соо от юзера и, если кол-во символов превышает 9 шт, то отправлять соо, что юзеру надо отправлять соо по-другому?

Конечно, я предложил шаблон, а как вы будете его использовать в своем проекте, это ваше решение.
